# design : multiple users moderating comment system

Tags: mysql, algorithm, web

I am trying to find a good solution for multiple users (moderators) to work on a general commenting system.

What I currently have
+Mysql table of id, userid, comment, date, status

The unapproved comments are shown in the moderator page by selecting all unapproved comments. Once a moderator views the comment, they can approve/delete by using appropriate button (It is simple changing status or delete statement). This works fine if there is only one moderator.

If there is more than one moderator, how can I ensure consistency between them. For example, once the fist moderator has approved/deleted a comment, how can I ensure that this particular comment is removed from all other moderators list. I can ensure on the mysql table that each comment is changed only once, but I do not want more than one moderator to be working on the same comment(waste of resources ;)

Answer (score 0):

If *all* moderators need to be able to see *all* comments, then there's no perfect solution: if moderator A and B both see comment X on a list of unapproved comments, both click "View", and A approves or rejects it before B does, then when B clicks "Accept" or "Reject", there is a conflict that must be resolved somehow.  Even if you somehow forced all browser sessions viewing the list of unapproved comments to be refreshed from the server side at the moment the update hits the DB, you can at most reduce the chances of such a conflict happening; there's always a small window in which B could click "Accept" or "Reject" when this is no longer a valid action.

You can either:

1. Assign (e.g. randomly or via round-robin) incoming comments to individual moderators at the time that they are made, so that each comment only ever appears in that moderator's list, or
2. Accept that a moderator might click "View", "Accept" or "Reject" on a stale comment, i.e. a comment that has already been accepted or rejected by another moderator, and handle this appropriately (e.g. with an error message, or by overriding the previous judgment).

If you go with approach 2, make sure that all your DB operations take place in a single transaction, and that you can determine whether or not the update succeeded afterwards; *don't* "check" with an initial `SELECT` and only then `UPDATE`, since then something else could sneak in in between these two commands.  (It might be possible to safely use separate `SELECT` and `UPDATE` commands in a single DB transaction, but only do this if you are sure you understand the concurrency model your DB uses; e.g. with PostgreSQL, I believe you would need to add `FOR UPDATE` to the original `SELECT` in the usual `READ COMMITTED` transaction isolation level.)

I would recommend simply

```
UPDATE comments
SET status = true
WHERE userid = ?
AND id = ?
AND status = false
```

The last line means that you will be able to check whether the command actually succeeded by checking the number of rows affected: if some other moderator snuck in a change before you could, this will be 0 instead of 1.